# Autofac DynamicProxy with type parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, castle-dynamicproxy

I want to use Autofac's type interception to cache method results.

I registered my types with code below

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dependentAssemblies)
            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InterceptAttribute), true).Any())
            .WithParameters(parameters)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
            .InstancePerRequest();
```

And it works fine.
But this is Interface interception.
When i register types with

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dependentAssemblies)
            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InterceptAttribute), true).Any())
            .WithParameters(parameters)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .EnableClassInterceptors()
            .InstancePerRequest();
```

I get error

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Castle.Proxies.MyServiceProxy' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'System.String ' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor[], System.String, System.String, NLog.ILogger)'.

My params list is equal in both cases and is enough to create MyService 
and looks like

```
var parameters = new[]
        {
            new NamedParameter("name1", "value1"),
            new NamedParameter("name2", "value2")
        };
```

Have i forgot something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interceptors get wrapped around *services* (the `As<T>` part), not *components* (the concrete thing getting registered). You're registering things *as interfaces* but you're not enabling *interface interception*, you're enabling *class interception*. There aren't any classes to intercept.

Either *also* add `.AsSelf()` to that registration statement or switch back to `EnableInterfaceInterceptors()`.

Comment: Can i intercept components?

Comment: I inject dependencies via interfaces, but i need autofac to create proxies for components, to handle cache or smth. Is it possible?

Comment: You can only intercept services. [Decorators may get you what you want.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html)

Comment: Meybe you should add link to you answer, it's very usefull